# Помогите выразить член из формулы

Tags: javascript, математика, css-animation, линейная-алгебра

коллеги!
Есть такая вот формула расчёта скорости анимации
`let tempValue = 10 ** (2 - value / maxValue * 3);`
Почти прекрасно работает.
Но мне нужно теперь отсюда выразить value. Пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: `(2-lg(temp))*max/3`

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = 10 ** (2 - val/max * 3)
log10(temp) = 2 - val/max * 3
val = (2 - log10(temp)) / 3 * max
val = (2 - log10(temp)) * max / 3
```